# Edit raw resource app not installed

Tags: android, batch-file, compilation, apk, apktool

I made a project that insert a unique key inside a raw resource in android apk with bat file using `apk` manager.

I call the bat file with 2 parameters:

`batfile.bat moddedprojectname uniquekey`

Here is my code so far.

```
set PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin"
set parent2="apkmanager\other"
set szip="%parent2%\7za.exe"
set projectsource="apkmanager\place-apk-here-for-modding\originalfile.apk"
%szip% x -tzip "%projectsource%" -o"apkmanager\place-apk-here-for-modding\unzip%1"
set filedb="apkmanager\place-apk-here-for-modding\unzip%1\res\raw\a.db"
<nul set /p "=%2" > %filedb%
cd apkmanager\place-apk-here-for-modding\unzip%1\
set unszip="..\..\other\7za.exe"
%unszip% a -tzip ..\%1modded.apk *
cd ..\..\..
jarsigner -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore apkmanager/keystore/mykeys.keystore -storepass loanpro -keypass loanpro apkmanager/place-apk-here-for-modding/%1modded.apk loanpro
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs apkmanager/place-apk-here-for-modding/%1modded.apk
set zipalign="%parent2%\zipalign.exe"
%zipalign% -v 4 apkmanager/place-apk-here-for-modding/%1modded.apk apkmanager/place-apk-here-for-modding/done%1modded.apk
```

I managed to insert the unique key but when I install the modded apk it always gives me 'app not installed'. Any suggestion? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

updated:
I generated a certificate using keytool, signed the apk, and zipalign the apk but it still give me this error.

Comment: You should sign and align the modified file - see http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signing-manually

Comment: updated: I generated a certificate using keytool, signed the apk, and zipalign the apk but it still give me this error

Comment: Run logcat (directly from the command line, not through your IDE) during or shortly after the install attempt and find out what the actual complaint is.